# Why can't a file as swap be used for hibernation in Linux?

Tags: linux, swap, hibernate

I was trying to hibernate my Fedora 27 system temporarily using a swap file and failed. Answers in the following question also say that a dedicated swap partition must be used to hibernate the system and a swap file won't work.

[Why does Linux use a swap partition rather than a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/why-does-linux-use-a-swap-partition-rather-than-a-file)

I'm using an ext3 file system in which I created the swap file. What is stopping it being used for hibernation?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/swsusp-and-swap-files.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/swsusp-and-swap-files.txt) (link provided by @don_crissti), the system must locate the swap file's header, but in order to do this the filesystem that contains the swap file must be mounted, and a journaled filesystem (as ext3 is) cannot be mounted during resume from disk.

Quoting from the document:

> In order to use a swap file with swsusp, you need to:
>
> 1) Create the swap file and make it active, eg.
>
> `# dd if=/dev/zero of=<swap_file_path> bs=1024 count=<swap_file_size_in_k>`
>
> `# mkswap <swap_file_path>`
>
> `# swapon <swap_file_path>`
>
> 2) Use an application that will bmap the swap file with the help of the
>   FIBMAP ioctl and determine the location of the file's swap header, as the
>   offset, in `<PAGE_SIZE>` units, from the beginning of the partition which
>   holds the swap file.
>
> 3) Add the following parameters to the kernel command line:
>
> `resume=<swap_file_partition> resume_offset=<swap_file_offset>`
>
> where `<swap_file_partition>` is the partition on which the swap file is located
>   and `<swap_file_offset>` is the offset of the swap header determined by the
>   application in 2) (of course, this step may be carried out automatically
>   by the same application that determines the swap file's header offset using the
>   FIBMAP ioctl)
>
> OR
>
> Use a userland suspend application that will set the partition and offset
>   with the help of the SNAPSHOT_SET_SWAP_AREA ioctl described in
>   Documentation/power/userland-swsusp.txt (this is the only method to suspend
>   to a swap file allowing the resume to be initiated from an initrd or initramfs
>   image).

Comment: Does anybody know a program calculating the offset?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, I've written a big documentation [in this SO reply](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132154/29219), globally it is working by using `uswsusp` and configuring initramfs & Grub correctly.

Comment: Yours looks like a more useful version of the Debian handbook article on the subject. https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition