# Problems with session lock

Tags: xfce, guix

I am currently trying to get the session lock running on my DELL XPS 15.
Everytime I suspend the system it fails and there is an error message telling
me that all session lock tools failed. When booting it already reports a problem with
setuid command (which I don't entirely understand what it means).

I tried configuring my system according to the [guix documentation](https://guix.gnu.org/en/cookbook/en/guix-cookbook.html#Xorg) here but even after installing slock the executable is not in /bin/sloc but in /run/setuid-programs/ so I changed the configuration file like so:

```
                 (service screen-locker-service-type
                      (screen-locker-configuration
                       (name "slock")
                       (program (file-append slock "/run/setuid-programs/slock"))))
```

If anyone has got this running even with another set of screenlockers I would be happy
to adopt. At the moment I am just confused because I am unfamiliar with setuid and the underlying processes happening there in the OS.

Comment: There is two things there, 1st is do you have swap on your installation (can be checked by `swapon -s` if you only have a /dev/zram0 then check for swap on disk creation (you cannot suspend the system as swap is used to store current system status and /dev/zram0 is RAM so lost during suspend), 2nd is setuid which allows users to run some commands as root/administrator in this case slock.

Comment: Okay thanks already. I checked swapon -s but that returned nothing so I guess there is now swap space. Is there a way to add swap space post installation?

Comment: There is two ways to create swap. If you have some spare space on your disk then you can create a swap partition (recommended size is at least the memory size) or if you don't have space on disk create a file like it's described here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/why-does-linux-use-a-swap-partition-rather-than-a-file/2208#2208

Comment: Thanks now the suspend works after using a swap file. Still with the slock command it didn't work  until I configured the xfce4-screensaver in the guix config file. Still some strange things happen when closing the lid and configure session lock the system is unusable after waking up but for now that is not so important. Could be some settings in the DELL XPS Bios.